# Can i edit template of Bootbox.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootbox

Hi I have a problem regarding template of bootbox.js,
I want to change the following section:

```
closeButton:
  "<button type='button' class='bootbox-close-button close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>",
```

This is standard close button.
I just want to change it to my icon in some other js file for example(app.js) for the whole project.

I can't edit and commit file bootbox.js because it is bower file and this doesn't help me...

Comment: http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#dialog-options -- I think you want to take a look at `buttons` option

Comment: `bootbox.confirm({
                buttons: {
                    cancel: {
                        label: '',
                        className:"i-close"
                    }
                }
            });`

Comment: This one doesn't work for me. And broke all js code.

Comment: The `buttons` option is just used for the "action" buttons at the bottom of the dialog. There isn't a library function for changing the markup of the close button; `closeButton` is simply used for toggling the display of the close button. I assume when you say "I can't edit and commit file bootbox.js because it is bower file" that you mean that you're using bower to load the file?